# convert a text file of a grid of letters into a 2-d array where all the letters are their own index java

Tags: java

I've been trying to convert this into a 2-D array, where every character is an index and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
public static void readfile(String filename) {
    Scanner scanner = null;

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add an example file that is inputed

Comment: I'm passing it in as an argument and it looks like this

Comment: 6
6
y c o d e j
h s e y p k
l p h b w a
l o b w x z
w o b a a i
p l y y c g

Comment: The two top letters are the width and height

Comment: It's a 6 by 6 grid or it can be any type of even grid

Comment: first read the width and height and set the array size. Then do nested for-loop to read and assign the characterers

Comment: not sure how to access the width and height

Comment: use `scanner.nextInt()`.

Comment: what should i put instead of void if i want to return that grid